# Aplicação Rest em PHP com usuário Logado

Tags: php, angularjs, rest

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP Rest API. Esta aplicação será acessada via Web e Mobile.

Acontece que os usuários deverão se logar para poder consumir o serviço Rest.

A minha duvida - Como faço para manter os usuário logados numa aplicação REST?

Obs. Pretendo utilizar AngularJs no front-end

Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, o seu front-end é irrelevante, eu diria. Você pode armazenar os dados do usuário em cookie ou storage (o angular possui esse serviço já integrado), preferencialmente cookie que você pode controlar a validade, e sempre que for necessário verificar se o usuário está logado, você envia essas informações ao servidor e faz a validação.

Exemplo: gerar um token com algumas informações de login a ser verificada, como email, id e nome de modo criptografado.

A ideia básica é essa. Armazene alguma informação em cookie, sempre que o usuário acessar o app ou acessar alguma área restrita, envie esse cookie ao server e faça a validação da autenticação do usuário.

Comment: Obrigado Celsom, vou tentar da forma indicada!